# i am running windows 10 version 1909, and i keep on getting a message that says there were problems when trying to install updates?

Tags: windows-10, updates

I keep on clicking the retry button and keep getting the same message.
The message that I keep on getting says that there were problems installing some updates, but we'll retry again later:

> 2020-02 Cumulative Update for windows 10 version 1909 for x86 based systems (KB4532693)-Error 0x8e5e0147.

How do I go about fixing it?
I have even tried rebooting and checking for updates and nothing seems to work.

Comment: Microsoft rescinded `KB4532693` you absolutely do not want to install that update.  This is a Windows Update cache problem.  If you were to clear the [cache](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/windows-update-resources) the update no longer would attempt to be installed.

Comment: @user1143155 - You run `winver` through the run command. I rejected your edit to this question due to the fact it changes which patch the author was asking about.

Answer (score 1):

Run the steps in the Microsoft Update Troubleshooter.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971058

Follow the first step (that includes a script) to reset update components.

> This script will completely reset the Windows Update client settings.
>   It has been tested on Windows 7, 8, 10, and Windows Server 2012 R2. It
>   will configure the services and registry keys related to Windows
>   Update for default settings. It will also clean up files related to
>   Windows Update, in addition to BITS related data.

If that does not work, follow the Manual Steps below. Normally the first step works.

The script is a Powershell script. Download :
Reset-WindowsUpdate.ps1

Note: As of this post (Feb 23, 2020) avoid KB4532693. Microsoft will reissue it when it is fixed.

Comment: `KB4532693` is known to have problems.  While this will refresh/reset Windows Update you really should avoid installing `KB4532693`.

Comment: I had some "Stopped Working" issues after the day that update was issued and did a Repair Install (Advice from several articles on Runtime Broker). No errors or issues since but KB523693 does not show as an installed update on my system, so I agree with advice to avoid it (at least for the time being).

Comment: If it’s actually installed it should show up, but Microsoft removed the update, with plans to replace it in the future

Comment: The article to reset updates should get updates running, but since it is after the date rescinded it will not install. It is not on my laptop but I just checked my Desktop and the particular update is installed but not causing any issues. I expect Microsoft will reissue: add if not there; fix what is there.

Comment: If you have no issues keep the update installed;  It was optional anyway (D Update); They just prevented anyone else installing it.