# Why do I keep getting a 2020-03 cumulative update for Windows 10 version 1909 for x86 based systems (KB4551762) - error 0x8e5e0147?

Tags: windows-10, updates, windows-10-v1909

Why do I keep getting a 2020-03 cumulative update for Windows 10 version 1909 for x86 based systems (KB4551762) - error 0x8e5e0147?

I keep clicking on retry and keep on getting the same message each month.  I reboot the tablet and nothing seems to work.

How do I go about fixing the problem? Only it has a different date for each month it seemed to work on one day and the next the same problem starts popping up again.

Comment: Have you looked up the error to see what others have tried or what Microsoft documents say about this error?

Comment: Please specify the last cumulative update that was successfully installed.  We also need to know which build you are running, you can use `winver`, to determine that information.  Instead of an unformatted comment, please edit your question, and include this vital information.  Please also run the Windows Update troubleshooter, from the possible duplicate, after you provide us the information I have asked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [i am running windows 10 version 1909, and i keep on getting a message that says there were problems when trying to install updates?](https://superuser.com/questions/1527740/i-am-running-windows-10-version-1909-and-i-keep-on-getting-a-message-that-says)